# Gulp watch not working on imported less file

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-less

I'm trying to compile all the `.less` files to css, and leave `.import.less` files unprocessed (similar to Meteor less package). My file structure is as follow:

```
assets/less/normalize.less
assets/less/main.less
assets/less/header.import.less
assets/less/footer.import.less
assets/less/...
```

My `lessCompile` task **works fine** by itself (i.e. run it manually by `gulp lessCompile`).

```
gulp.task('lessCompile', function() {
    gulp.src(['assets/less/main.less', '!assets/less/*.import.less'])
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(autoprefix('last 2 version'))
        .pipe(minifyCSS({ advanced: true }))
        .pipe(concat('style.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/stylesheets'));
});
```

Now I add a watch to all the `.less` files to automate the compilation.

```
gulp.task('default', ['lessCompile'], function () {
    gulp.watch('assets/less/*.less', ['lessCompile']);
});
```

**Problem** is after I edited `assets/less/footer.import.less` , `lessCompile` task re-ran itself and all the styles in `footer.import.less` disappeared from the minified `style.min.css`. The same disappearance goes for editing any other `*.import.less` such as `header.import.less`. Also, there are no errors during the re-compile process.

Comment: The source path `'assets/less/*.less'` is watching all `*.less` files in the `assets/less/` path including your `*.import.less` files. Did you mean to not include them?

Comment: I actually mean to include them such that when I make changes to `assets/less/footer.import.less` the gulp `lessCompile` task will re-compile `main.less` and import the `footer.import.less`

Comment: Doesn't the import happen in the `main.less` file already? Using `@import "footer.import.less";`?

Comment: Yes, the `main.less` imports all the `*.import.less` files. And I simply need a trigger to re-compile `mail.less` after I made changes to any `*.import.less` files.

Comment: Do you have a public repository of the gulp project?  That may help to debug if we get the same issue. You could always create one with just the less and gulp tasks.

Comment: So, all the `*.import` files are getting imported by `main.less`? What I find weird is your gulp.src, which actually just could point to `main.less` alone. I recreated your setup and given the circumstances it works fine... I'm with talves to see some sort of public repo where we could recreate it

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I found the solution that simply add a `return` before `gulp.src` to activate async and using a callback function in the `gulp.watch` that run `gulp.start('lessCompile')` to reran the whole task.